# Custom Post Types and Pre Populated Custom Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm building a custom post type that relies on three custom taxonomies.   I'm registering all the custom posts and tax...  using the init action (this works and I can manage the new aspects)

```
...
register_taxonomy( 'cppstrands', array( 'cppstatements' ), $args );
...

//Part of the cppmatrix_init method called here
add_action( 'init', 'cppmatrix_init', 0 );
...
```

I am also trying to prepopulate the tax.. with data when the plugin is activated using register_activation_hook but this fails as Taxonomy does not exist.

```
...
if(taxonomy_exists('cppstrands')) ...
...

//Part of the cppmatrix_dataInstall called here
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cppmatrix_dataInstall');
```

I am suspecting that *init* happens before *register_activation_hook* but don't know what to do to solve it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting everything into the init call and then calling a check on the tax.. to see if it was empty.

I'm not convinced that this is the most elegant solution or efficient so maybe someone will correct or confirm what I have found as a solution.